# ui-select within ng-repeat is broken

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code, in each loop only the first multiselect is working the rest are been displayed but they are broken.
They been displayed but it seems that they are not binded correctly, when I choose an option is not been displayed as selected it just disappears.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="mdf in wrap.item | orderItemAttributes">
  <label>{{ mdf.modifier.display }}</label>
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="somemodel[mdf.id]" theme="bootstrap" close-on-select="false" title="mdf.modifier.display" ng-if="mdf.modifier.max !== 1">
       <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick many">{{ $item.name }}</ui-select-match>
         <ui-select-choices repeat="option in mdf.options track by option.name">
            <div>{{ option.name | highlight:for_user }}
            <span ng-if="!mdf.modifier.free">, +{{ option.price }}</span></div>
         </ui-select-choices>
     </ui-select>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way are they broken?  Not rendering correctly, not showing the options, not binding correctly?  Can you include the HTML output?  Does `somemodel[mdf.id]` exist for the subsequent items?

Comment: do you have any duplicates in --> option.name?

Comment: Yes I have found one mdf.id duplicate,  could that brake everything ?

Comment: No I don't have a duplicate on option.name